# Unable to intercept 404 error by mail in production (debug=False)

Tags: django, error-handling

I try to configure django app to receive trace of error (404 and 500) when my app will be in production.
I've read Django documentation and configure settings accordingly.
I generate 404 error in my code, but receive no email with settings below.

```
ADMINS = [('John', 'john@example.com'), ]
MANAGERS = [('John', 'john@example.com'), ]
SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html': True,
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS` setting was removed in version 1.8, so that won't work.

You need to include `django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware` in your middleware settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware',
     # ... other middleware ...
]
```

---

Heed this note from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/error-reporting/#errors):

> `BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware` must appear before other middleware that intercepts 404 errors, such as `LocaleMiddleware` or `FlatpageFallbackMiddleware`. Put it towards the top of your MIDDLEWARE setting.

Comment: thanks for replying... I had 'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware' include but doesn't works...